# Erroneous author name for a commit in bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm working with *Git terminal on MacOS*. If I push a commit and see historical of the repo in bitbucket I can see a ***different author' name*** than expected.

In local, I have configured my name and email in Git globally. If I get the user using the command:

```
git config --get user.name
```

I have the correct name, for example: ***MyName***. If I do a push, it appears as Author: ***Master Account***, for what it's worth).

I remove old credentials of Git and set newly.

I also be using Vagrant boxes. When I push from within Vagrant, as author of the commit appears ***Vagrant***. Within Vagrant I also configure the global ones and I keep appearing ***Vagrant*** on the remote...

This issue occur in two different accounts. In one, have setted the public SSH key in Bitbucket so I push to it without introduce credentials. I have tried in a second bitbucket personal account that need entering username and password to send the commits and the problem is the same. Also, it deleted the keys of the MAC keys related to git, bitbucket... no changes.

How to make ***MyName*** appear as an author in Bitbucket?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/k88hudson/git-flight-rules/blob/master/README.md might have the answer?

Comment: I tried with this page, the author give interesting tips but I didn't solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you push your code on Bitbucket or GitHub and you see the commit author name is wrong.

You can change your commit author name using some basic commands.

1. You need to check the config details using this command
   ( git config --list )
2. The list is in front of you and you can see the detail over there. If the details are wrong like name & email you can change it using this command.

For change user name which will mention in the commit section after when you will commit your code on bitbucket or GitHub.

For change user name / Author name:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

For change email:

```
git config --global user.email "Your Email "
```

Now verify again using this command:

```
git config --list
```